# Blackberry development on Windows XP

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have installed Blackberry JDE on Windows XP. And I am trying to run the 'samples.jdw' on simulator on Blackberry JDE. So I do 'Debug->Go' But when I do that
I get this popup windows saying 'Cannot find file' net_rim_bis_client__ru.debug'.

And there is 'Search...', 'Brwose...', 'Cancel', 'Don't ask this again' button.

So how can I get the sample project run on simulator in Blackberry JDE?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the debugger, then you can (1) build the project in JDE, (2) start the simulator (Windows "Start" > "Programs" > "Research In Motions" > "BlackBerry JDE x.x.x" > "Device Simulator") and (3) when it is ready just load the built .cod file via simulator menu item "File" > "Load Java Programm.." (at least this is the name of the menu item on my Storm 9530 simulator). This adds the app to the simulator (the app icon appears on the simulator).

Comment: Also I'm not 100% sure, but I believe it should be possible to start the app via 'Debug->Go'. You should just tell JDE to ignore that .debug file absence. This simply means some code (related to net_rim_bis_client__ru) will not be covered with debugger.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that - depending on exactly which file(s) it says are missing - you can safely ignore these messages (click on the 'do not show this message again') button.

I got messages about a whole bunch of missing files, and have ignored them without any apparent problems:

- net_rim_bis_client__ru
- net_rim_bis_client__ru-1
- net_rim_bis_client__cs
- net_rim_bis_client__cs-1
- net_rim_bis_client__el
- net_rim_bis_client__el-1
- net_rim_bis_client__pl
- net_rim_bis_client__pl-1
- net_rim_bis_client__it
- net_rim_bis_client__it-1

... and so on. They appear to be related to localisation, so perhaps if I wanted to set the simulator language to Russian I might run into problems.

Anyway, it appears we are [not alone](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Debugging-Errors/m-p/1552027#M190482) in having this problem (see also the response immediately following that post). Maybe one day RIM will actually release some dev tools that work properly, but I'm not holding my breath...